# Catching global errors in React

Tags: reactjs

So a general React question about error handling if anybody knows. For reasons, i was trying to do the following

```
try {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
} catch (error) {
    console.log("CAUGHT AN ERROR!!!!!!!")
    console.log(error);
   //send the entire redux state to the server and notify some services, then rethrow
    throw error;
}
```

Then i realised this doesnt work and i was wondering why.

By "it doesnt" work i mean, the Error bubbles up all the way to index.js which is the file that contains the ReactDOM.render code but it never really gets caught by my catch.

If anyone can explain why to me i'd be grateful.

EDIT: There's this thing https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html called Error Boundaries in React but this seems to only work if the error is thrown from Render.. My error is thrown in a different Component class method

Comment: It should work for any lifecycle method.

Comment: so assume my hierarchy is App -> Comp1 -> Comp2. Should an error thrown on a class method of Comp2 be caught on the componentDidCatch of App if thats the only componentDidCatch defned?

Comment: It seems that Error Boundaries don't really work when error occures in the custom methods of the Component classes.

Comment: okay, so then, what is a general way to capture errors generated there? and why isnt my way working if the Error object isnt captured by anyone?

Comment: You may want to post the problematic code.

Comment: This is a general question , not an implementation specific one im afraid. I think what really is the problem here is that theres no other way than window.onerror to catch errors thrown by functions such as onclick settimeout and generally things put in the event loop. My line of thought is problematic from the getgo as im thinking of JS as a single entry point language when in reality a function stack doesnt always pop back down to a main ().